# angular DI with abstract class token

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

The angular docs show how you can't use an interface as an injection token:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#typescript-interfaces-arent-valid-tokens

```
export interface AppConfig {
  apiEndpoint: string;
  title: string;
}

export const HERO_DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'api.heroes.com',
  title: 'Dependency Injection'
};

export class MyComponent {
  // FAIL! Can't inject using the interface as the parameter type
  constructor(private config: AppConfig) { }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      // FAIL! Can't use interface as provider token
      provide: AppConfig,
      useValue: HERO_DI_CONFIG
    }
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Is there anything wrong with using an abstract class as an injection token:

```
export abstract class AppConfig {
  public abstract apiEndpoint: string;
  public abstract title: string;
}

export const HERO_DI_CONFIG: AppConfig = {
  apiEndpoint: 'api.heroes.com',
  title: 'Dependency Injection'
};

export class MyComponent {
  // should work
  constructor(private config: AppConfig) { }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      // class exists at runtime
      provide: AppConfig,
      useValue: HERO_DI_CONFIG
    }
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Or is that exploiting Typescript?

Edit: I know the documentation uses InjectionToken but what is wrong with using the abstract class for a token? It is more type safe then `constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) config: AppConfig)`, you could just lie and put `constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) config: string)`.

Comment: You *can* inject class that implements interface/extends abstract class. Use `InjectionToken` (that is literally next paragraph in link you provided).

Comment: Why not using a concrete class `AppConfig`?

Comment: As mentioned, use a injection token

Comment: I know InjectionToken is a solution but is there any thing wrong with the abstract class solution, that is the question.

Comment: That will work but why you want to use an abstract class for it? You know an InjectionToken can be typed right? (e.g. `new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('hero:di:config')`)

Comment: @cyrix yes I know the InjectionToken constructor take generic parameter and claims "This provides additional level of type safety." - https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken but I don't see how.